# Remove Grub from original boot drive

Tags: boot, grub2

I have been running Ubuntu 18.04.3 quite happily for some time without issue.  Last week, I got the bug to move from a 1TB hdd to a 1TB ssd.  I thought running dd (yes, I know data destroyer - lol) to duplicate the drive, generate and assign a new UUID to the ssd, change fstab, reboot, and all would be good.  Alas, that is not the case.

It seems as though I start up from the ssd, but then boot from the hdd.  I can mount the ssd and everything is the same, but I can't seem to get the ssd to run grub and boot.

I tried to unplug the hdd, but then grub rescue shows up, and will not boot to the new ssd.  I get an error (in a grub looking screen, not the OS) saying grub can't find the UUID (of the hdd).  I am not sure what file to edit so that grub on the ssd looks for the UUID of the ssd instead of the hdd.

Comment: You at least have to reinstall grub. Often just easier to do a total new install to a new drive, and do a restore from your backup. Becomes a good way to confirm your backup is complete as you still have old drive to go back to in case you are missing something. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Here's my boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cRYSmv2NDj/

sda is the hdd, sdb is the ssd, sdc is another ssd, but that can be disconnected and won't impact anything.  It seems like I'm almost there.

Comment: After some fiddling with boot repair, moving things around and getting familiar with grub rescue and UUIDs, I finally have it fixed.  Would have been much simpler to just install and restore a backup as you said.

Comment: If using gpt and BIOS boot you need a bios_grub partition 1 or 2MB unformatted with bios_grub flag on that drive for grub to correctly install. I see one only on sdb. Since new systems are UEFI, I like to have both the bios_grub &  an ESP as first two partitions. Then drive could easily be converted to UEFI boot with install of UEFI version of grub. I started that two years before I had an UEFI system for all new or totally reformatted drives including larger flash drives.